# Convert InputMismatchException into user-defined exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I want my code to change the name of `InputMismatchException` into `NotANumberException`.
This is my code and it's forming an error if I input a non-numeric character. How should I fix this?

Main Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grade {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int grade;
        String remark;
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
            grade = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch(NotANumberException e){
            System.out.println(e.notgetMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NotANumberException extends InputMismatchException{

   public String notgetMessage(){
      return "You did not input a number. Please try again!";
   }

}
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? whats the purpose?

Comment: Your homework assignment requires you to create a custom exception class?

Comment: Yeah, we need to use a user defined function instead of a default exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot catch an exception of subtype of InputMismatchException in your code.

Also you cannot change the java.util `Scanner.nextInt` method to throw your custom exception class because it is util library by Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

**Possible solution for your assignement is**

Create a method in your first class which returns int

```
public class Grade {

    //New method
    public int getIntegerInput() throws NotANumberException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
           return input.nextInt();
        } catch( InputMismatchException e) {
            throw new NotANumberException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int grade;
        String remark;
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
            grade = getIntegerInput();
        }
        catch(NotANumberException e){
            System.out.println(e.notgetMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

PS: As you are saying this is an assignment, You try to put effort on learning Java Type system and extending exception class and adding throws signature. This is just a prototype to help your assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You must catch the exception that the Scanner class actually throws and then do something with it, like create and throw your custom exception.

```
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        throw new NotANumberException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.geek.test;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test4 {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int grade;
    String remark;
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
            grade = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("You did not input a number. Please try again!");

        }
    }
```

}